# No sapjco3 in java.library.path Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, sapjco3

I'm getting this error when i run code.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path
```

I have added the jar(**sapjco-3.0.jar**) to folder and did set the path in the project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the native implementation of the sap java connector. sapjco consists of a .jar for the java binding and a native library (an .so-file) for the platform specific binding.

You need an account on the sap service marketplace to access it. If you have one go to http://service.sap.com and there to Software Downloads / INstallations and upgrades / Browse / SAP Connectors / SAP JCO

Comment: The SAP Service Marketplace has reached its end of life. It has been replaced by the SAP Support Portal (and other sites). The new link to the JCo Homepage is now: [https://support.sap.com/jco](https://support.sap.com/jco)

Answer (score -2):

Once you place sapjco3.dll, Do not forget to restart your eclipse with **Admin** rights.